# Dynamically filtering linq lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently trying doing the following.

```
var groups = MileId == null ? test.Groups.Where(x => x.ProjectId == ProjectId)
                            : test.Groups.Where(x => x.Milestone == MileId &&
                                                     x.ProjectId == ProjectId);
```

But I also have additional terms that I need to filter groups by:

```
foreach (var ChartItem in ChartItems)
{
     foreach (var StatusItem in ChartItem.ChartStatusItems)
     {
          foreach (var PriorityItem in StatusItem.ChartPriorityItems)
          {
              filteredgroups.AddRange(
                  groups.Where(x => x.Status   == StatusItem.StatusID
                                &&  x.Priority == PriorityItem.PriorityID));
          }
     }
}
```

This is fine and it works but the nested foreach loops is pretty slow when adding the ranges. If I groups.toList() before the loop, then that statement is slow and the nested loops are fast.

My question is:

Would it be possible to filter groups from the start based on those StatusIds and PriorityIds dynamically? How?

Stackoverflow recommends some articles on Expression Tree's based on my subject line... is that what I need to look into?

Thank you

EDIT:

So I'm doing this now:

```
        foreach (var ChartItem in ChartItems)
        {
            foreach (var StatusItem in ChartItem.ChartStatusItems)
            {
                foreach (var PriorityItem in StatusItem.ChartPriorityItems)
                {

                    var groups = MileId == null ? test.Groups.Where(x => x.ProjectId == InspectorProjectId &&
                                                                                    x.Status == StatusItem.StatusID &&
                                                                                    x.Priority == PriorityItem.PriorityID)
                                                       : test.Groups.Where(x => x.Milestone == InspectorMileId &&
                                                                                    x.ProjectId == InspectorProjectId &&
                                                                                    x.Status == StatusItem.StatusID &&
                                                                                    x.Priority == PriorityItem.PriorityID);

                    filteredgroups.AddRange(groups);
                }
            }
        }
```

It's a big improvement but it's still going to the slow 'test' server for each priority. If I could get it all filtered in 1 go, it would be ideal.

EDIT 2: Oh I don't have access to the db directly :( we access it through an API.

Comment: What is `test.Groups`? Is that accessing a database? Approximately how many items does the list contain?

Comment: Yeah, that is correct, test.groups is accessing a database. groups contains about 10k items before filtering.

Answer (score 4):

**All this should be happening in the database**. Just create a view that joins all those tables. It's hard to be faster than a database when intersecting and joining sets of data.

Comment: Yeah I ended up optimizing it a similar way (see Edit). What do you recommended?

Comment: I'm afraid creating a view is not an option because I don't have access to the db directly. Instead we communicate with it through an API.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do it with `Contains`?

```
var filteredgroups =
  test.Groups.Where(x => 
    (MileId == null || x.Milestone == MileId) // (replaces ?: in original)
    && x.ProjectId == ProjectId
    && ChartItem.ChartStatusItems.Contains(x.Status) 
    && StatusItem.ChartPriorityItems.Contains(x.Priority));
```

(I'm not sure how Linq-to-Sql and Linq-to-Objects are going to interact wrt performance, but at least it's concise...)

Comment: I actually ended up doing something similar here too but instead of using contains I just 
x.Status == StatusItem.StatusID &&                                                                                         x.Priority == PriorityItem.PriorityID

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` loops are most likely executing a deferred call, which is most likely hitting your database on each `foreach` loop. But you don't have to, using `SelectMany` you can simply build up your query:

```
var statuses = ChartItems
                   .SelectMany(x => x.ChartStatusItems)
                   .Select(i => i.StatusId);
var priorities = ChartItems
                     .SelectMany(x => x.ChartPriorityItems)
                     .Select(i => i.PriorityId); 

var filtered = groups.Where(x => statuses.Contains(x.Status) &&
                                 priorities.Contains(x.Priority))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can call `.Any()` within your `.Where()` and skip the loops entirely.

```
test.Groups.Where(x => (MileId == null || 
                                                 x.Milestone == MileId) && 
                                                 x.ProjectId == ProjectId && 
                                                 ChartItems.Any(c => c.ChartStatusItems.Any(s => s.StatusId == x.StatusId && 
                                                     s.ChartPriorityItems.Any(p => p.PriorityId == x.PriorityId))));
```